# word breaking/word splitting in verbatimTextOutput in shiny

Tags: r, split, shiny, cpu-word

I have been through similar topics but I did not find my answer.
I would like to know if somebody found a solution for the word splitting in VerbatimTextOuput in shiny. Here is an example with split words. How to do for them to not split (without using the scroll bar)?

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("TxtOut")))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$TxtOut <- renderText(
    "a longish text that goes over multiple lines and breaks words"
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you !
Cheers